# Modify step text in cucumber before matching

Tags: cucumber

We have some configuration issues that we would like to solve by putting in "special constants" in Cucumber. For example, we would like anywhere that the text `"__USER__"` is used in a step, that should be replaced with the current user running the app (so that we can test things like user permissions).

The strategy I was trying to take toward this was to do something like this:

```
BeforeStep do |step|
    domain = get_domain()
    username = get_username()
    step.text.gsub("__USER__", "#{domain}/#{username}")
end
```

However, there is no `BeforeStep`. I tried to use `Before do |scenario| ... end` but the scenario didn't have anything I could use on it. How can we replace instances of `"__USER__"` in our code with the user (and instances of `"__CURRENT_DATE__"` with the current date, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a case for writing more declarative steps such as `When the user logs in` as opposed to such things as `When I fill in "txt_user_name" with "fred"`.  It would be easy to write your step definition in that case:

```
When /^the user logs in$/ do
    domain = get_domain()
    username = get_username()
    fill_in "txt_user_name", :with => "#{domain}/#{username}"
end
```

You could even bring in a step argument transform to turn the text 'the user' into the username you need, so you don't have to repeatedly make the change:

```
CAPTURE_USER = Transform /^(the user)$/ do |this_isnt_used|
    domain = get_domain()
    username = get_username()
    "#{domain}/#{username}"
end

When /^(#{CAPTURE_USER }) logs in$/ do |user_name|
    puts "Logging in as #{user_name}"
end
```

This would match the step `Given the user logs in` and pass in the correct user name as a parameter.

Also, looking back at your question, you could use a transform to accomplish exactly what you were trying to do and have it replace instances of `__USER__`, but I wouldn't choose that option myself - it feels like it would impact the readability of the scenario too much.  Your choice though!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use cucumber to log a user in through the view then run tests from there.

Something like:

```
Given a user exists with email: "user@gmail.com", account_type: "customer" 
When I go to the homepage 
And I follow "Sign in" 
And I fill in "email" with "user@gmail.com" 
And I fill in "password" with "password" 
And I press "Sign in"
```